Task Scheduler Windows 11 not waking the computer
I know that variations of this have been asked previously and I have read most of the responses to older threads. However I am using a newer OS and those older threads have helped me get this far but have not solved my problem.
I have written a python script that I want to execute at 0700 every morning which checks some USGS stream gages and emails me the current discharge so that I can plan my field work for the day. I am using a Windows 11 OS. I have written a .bat file that calls the python script, and my scheduled task executes that .bat file, which executes the script. I have the Trigger set to begin the task on a schedule at 0700 and to recur every day. Security options are set to run whether I am logged on or not, and to run with the highest privileges. I also have the power condition set to wake the computer to run this task. I have enabled wake timers in the power options, and have disabled hibernation from the command line. When I tested the call by changing the timer and putting the computer to sleep during the day it woke the computer up, ran the script, and went back to sleep. But when I reset the timer for 0700 and went home for the weekend it did not run over the weekend (I did not receive any emails), but instead ran this morning when I arrived at work and manually woke my computer up. What else can I do at this point to have my computer wake up without fail every morning, even when I am several hours away in the field, where I really need this to work?

Windows sleep is very finnicky. Sometimes on wake - the files won't load, etc. I cannot give you ideas on making your current method more robust, but I can recommend using  the free tier of a cloud provider to host this script instead. If you take out the variable of sleep, you may have more consistent results.
